# Comparison Assignments in React Practical Tutorial

Tags: reactjs, comparison-operators

In react practical tutorial in section "Declaring a Winner", this code has been shown:

```
function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

It's a tic-tac-toe game, and I didn't understand how the comparisons here works (I understand the finale result, but not the process.). Can some one enlighten me?

Answer (score 2):

Lets break if condition and analyse it

```
if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
  return squares[a];
}
```

You can break if conditions, wherever && (AND) condition is there.
AND condition sequentially. whenever it finds the condition returns false next condition os not executed.
so conditions now are: 
1. squares[a]
2. squares[a] === squares[b]
3. squares[a] === squares[c]

From your code I can assume that **squares** is a big set of **array**

1. As First condition says, squares[a] which will look for the a index in the big squares array and return true if that element presents otherwise next condition is not executed at all.
2. In the second condition, it compares the values thats are present in the squares array for the index a and b. like squares[0] === squares[1]. that can be equal or not, it depends on the squares array you have it. If second condition fails then it will not execute third condition at all.
3. Same like condition 2, condition 3 is executed, where it compares values of squares array with the index b and c.

I hope It's clear. For better understanding, print the squares array and check it.

Answer (score 0):

it would be much better if they would explain like this:
In a tic-toe game squares[a] could be X or O, if squares[a] = X or O and not NULL it will compare squares[a] === squares[b] and squares[a] === squares[c]

If the comparison matches they are the same X X X or O O O, you have a winner, if they are X O X, it will be ignored no winning/no matching.

I struggle to understand coding, because sometimes I can't find an explanation with the reason why it was coded like that. Maybe it is a English language problem, I will begin to look in my native language o/